# Python: Multiprocessing Recipe for Queue(s) with Many Consumers

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue, recipe

Since I have been wasting a lot of time trying to `join()` workers in python `multiprocessing` architectures that get their tasks from a `multiprocessing.Queue`, which is at the same time fed by a feeder function through `put()`:

**Can someone contribute a short but robust recipe for this kind of architecture?**

Let's say up to 10 feeders and up to 100 workers. Queue items might be large.

I can only guess that in the past I have often had the queue busy and not responding anymore, but mostly, I had the task done, only the jobs never joined, or wether they joined or not seemed to depend on arbitrary parameters.

So imagine the following workflow:

- One or more `feeder()` jobs read from input (i.e. disk) and create tasks for the first line of workers. They put the tasks into a queue `Q`. When there are no more tasks to create, the feeders should join.
- Many workers take the tasks out of `Q` and process it. Then they put the result into another queue `R`. When these workers fail to get more jobs from `Q` and are done with the last task, they should join. Consider that they might see an exception due to invalid input/task. They should still join.
- Let's add another line of workers that takes always two results from `R`, merges them and puts the result back into `R`. When there is only one result left in `R`, all workers of the second line should join.
- Finally I can take the last remaining aggregated result out of `R` and be happy.

I think this setup should include enough aspects to allow for generalization of many different tasks.

To avoid blocking of the queue(s), I have already tried out the following ideas:

- Use multiple queues with always putting to the smallest queue and getting from **random** queue
- Do not block in `get()`, but try getting without wait, if fails, sleep for a short time and retry, keep track of number of tries, after a while, give up, assuming queue is empty.

I can add some code, but maybe this would lead to bug fixing instead of sharing best practices.